# Error during sbt execution while installing giter8 with conscript

Tags: scala, sbt

Running the latest Scala 2.9.0.1, followed the [SBT setup instructions](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Setup) and the [installation instructions of giter8](https://github.com/n8han/giter8#readme) I get;

```
Error during sbt execution: Label <html><body>You are being <a href="https is not in a section
```

What I did was:

1. Put the [`sbt-launch.jar`](http://typesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt-launch/0.10.0/sbt-launch.jar) in `~/bin`.
2. Created `~/bin/sbt` with the content being `java -Xmx512M -jar`dirname $0`/sbt-launch.jar "$@"`.
3. Installed [conscript](https://github.com/n8han/conscript#readme) using `curl https://raw.github.com/n8han/conscript/master/setup.sh | sh`
4. Tried to install giter8 via conscript using `cs n8han/giter8`, but I always end up with the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a [bug in conscript installer](https://github.com/n8han/giter8/issues/12) which the developer was able to fix.